# Change text button “add to cart” able to translation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I put in functions.php this code to change the label of the “add to cart” button of Woocommerce. Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'nlwc_custom_button_text' );

function nlwc_custom_button_text() {
    return __('Aggiungi ');
}
```

Is this solution able to be translated with Poedit(for example)?
I tried to insert this:

```
e_(‘Aggiungi’, ‘theme’);
```

instead of __('Aggiungi '), but WordPress returned me the text separated from the button.
How can I do to be able to translate the button add to cart in my theme?

I know that if don't modify it, Woocommerce translates the term "add to cart".

Thanks a lot to everyone who answers :)

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

you can use `_e` function to translite local texts   `_e('yout text', your theme)`

Comment: I found the solution, here is the right code:

```function nlwc_custom_button_text() {
return esc_html__('Show more ', 'theme');
}```